# How to align ggplot2 pie plot to the top in a shinyapp when the view window is narrow?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I’m writing a shinyapp that uses `splitLayout` to display two ggplot figures on the same line. However, the pie plot figure does not align to the top even when I set the “align:top” style. As you can see in the example below, when the view window is narrow, the pie plot appears at the vertical center with a lot of white space above it. I have tried other functions like `div` or `column` but they don’t work either. I think this might have something to do with ggplot’s graphic scaling rules. How can I get rid of the white space and make the pie plot align to the top?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 500)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      splitLayout(
        cellArgs = list(style = "align: top;"),
        plotOutput("plot1"),
        plotOutput("plot2")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- data.frame(x=letters[1:4], y=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4))
    ggplot(data, aes(x = "", y = y, fill = x))+
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')+
      coord_polar(theta = 'y')+
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            plot.background = element_rect(fill = "green"),
            panel.grid = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_blank())
    })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist))+
      geom_point()+
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "green"))
    )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried using the `div` method in UI, but it doesn’t work.

```
div(style = "vertical-align: top;margin:0;",
   div(style = "width:50%;float:left;posotion:top;",plotOutput("plot1")),
   div(style = "width:50%;float:right;",plotOutput("plot2")))
```

Note that sometimes I also have other modules that need to be displayed with the pie plot, such as `verbatimTextOutput`, so I can’t plot the two figures together.

Answer (score 0):

It is working when cellArgs is set as below:

```r
cellArgs = list(style = "align:top; position:top")
```

Comment: I modified cellArgs in the previous code, but I doubt that it resolved my problem. What else could be wrong? By the way, I’m using R 4.2.2, ggplot 3.4.1, and shiny 1.7.4.